# How to prevent line segments from overlapping on QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt5, qgraphicsitem

I Use QGraphicslineItem to represent the trajectory of the object,
In the timer function, the current QPoint(sence corinate system) is obtained each time, and the previous QPoint and the current QPoint are connected into a line segment.
My problem is that the tail of previous segment and the head of current segment  are superimposed.
code:

```
static QPointF lastpos;
getpos(currentpos);
QPen pen;
pen.setWidth(m_penPixes);
pen.setColor(QColor(192,192,192,120));
m_scene->addLine(lastpos.x(), lastpos.y(), currentpos.x(), currentpos.y(),pen);
lastpos = currentpos
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps instead of calling `addLine()` for each segment, you want to call `QGraphicsPathItem * myPathItem = addPath()` just once at startup, and then for each line segment you want to add, call `QPainterPath pp = myPathItem->path(); pp.lineTo(x, y); myPathItem->setPath(pp);`

Comment: I think if the motion is unidirectional, it should be OK to call addPath()
 ,but the movement of my object is repeated back and forth.
I think it should be related to the boundingrect and the pen width, but I don't know how to modify the boundingrect area